# Website layout changes when keyboard open on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, keyboard

I am making a website which is responsive so it should work on almost every device. I have a contact page with contact fields everything looks great on large screen devices and in mobile, tabs etc until I open keyboard to fill the contact form. When keyboard of phone appears for user to input everything breaks.

My problem is I want to show message to user when they change the orientation of the phone from portrait to landscape, to keep the orientation in portrait. When keyboard opens the message appears due to the css media query I used to show the message.

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
 /* Styles for Portrait screen */
 }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* Styles for Landscape screen */
 }
```

Please help me to hide the message when keybaord opens or any solution to completely off the orientation feature for my website.